# Why background is blinking on hover when I move mouse cursor in DP box

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

I am trying to create a DP box for the user which is containing a user profile picture in it, where on image hover an edit profile image link will appear, but it is not working. When I hover over on the image it is blinking and the link doesn't appear correctly.

Here is the codepan link [click here](http://codepen.io/rhulkashyap/pen/zrobep)

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
 body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.dp {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.edit-dp a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 130px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: none;
}
.dp img:hover ~ .edit-dp a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dp">
  <img src="http://rs618.pbsrc.com/albums/tt265/davejarrett/Avatars/check-in-minion_zps7ee060ac.jpg~c200" alt="" width="128">
  <div class="edit-dp">
    <a href="#">Edit Image</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/pqh04ypu) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *blinking* glitch is because of that `:hover` effect of `display: block` on `image` instead of container `div`.

Since every time you `:hover` on the image you ultimately gonna edit it, so instead of `display: none` you can set it to `opacity: 0` and on `:hover` you can set it to `opacity: 1` and by doing this you'll get a nice transition effect too.

Here's the **Snippet** for a better view:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.dp {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.edit-dp a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 130px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.dp:hover .edit-dp a {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="dp">
  <img src="http://rs618.pbsrc.com/albums/tt265/davejarrett/Avatars/check-in-minion_zps7ee060ac.jpg~c200" alt="" width="128">
  <div class="edit-dp">
    <a href="#">Edit Image</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome solution. You are really genius.

Comment: @RahulKashyap glad to help :)

Comment: Thanks @vivekkupadhyay you saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**

Use  following css will make your effect nice.

```
.dp:hover > .edit-dp a{
    display: block;
}
```

Make hover effect on div instead of image

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
 body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.dp {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.edit-dp a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 130px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: none;
}
.dp:hover > .edit-dp a{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dp">
  <img src="http://rs618.pbsrc.com/albums/tt265/davejarrett/Avatars/check-in-minion_zps7ee060ac.jpg~c200" alt="" width="128">
  <div class="edit-dp">
    <a href="#">Edit Image</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKbRWv)**

**Solution 2:**

And Another solution is use `pointer-events:none;` on hover.

```
.dp img:hover ~ .edit-dp a{
    display: block;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

**[Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJBomy)**